# Modify a paragraph element inside a div

Tags: jquery, dom

Need to add an element in a web page, cloning the actual.

```
console.log(($this));
```

Gives something like this:

```
<div id="id" class="class" style="style">
<p style="style">World</p>
</div>
```

I want to add word "Hello" with the exact same structure, before "World"

Tried with attr() or html() but replaces all the attributes.

Comment: If you want clone p: `$('p').clone().appendTo('#id');`

Comment: Just to clarify, `$this` gives you that html you pasted, and you want to copy (clone) that html and put it somewhere else? Or do you just want to modify whats there?

Comment: Copy that html div, and put it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentcontent=$("#id").find("p").text();
$("#id").find("p").text("Hello"+currentcontent);
```

This will do it for only one DIV with that particular ID (Id]s are unique)

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/trdxg/2/

If you want to do it for **n** number of elements with same structure, you can change your jQuery selector to use the `class`.

```
$(function(){
    $("div.class").each(function(index,item){
       var item=$(this);
        var currentcontent=item.find("p").text();
        item.find("p").text("Hello"+currentcontent); 

    }); 
});​
```

Sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/trdxg/7/

Answer (score 2):

One-liners ftw:

```
$("#id > p").prepend("Hello ");
```

Comment: Is this equivalent? element.find("p").prepend("Hello"); If it is, it overrides p attributes and text and leave it like this: <div ...><p>Hello</p></div>, same what attr() and html() methods did.

Comment: What? Got to test that! @jacktrades

Comment: doesn't matter my friend, u have my e-mail to contact me

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want to "clone the actual". Here's how you would clone `$this` and modify the clone's contents:

```
var $clone = $this.clone();
$clone.find('p').text(function(i, oldText){
    return "Hello " + oldText;
});
$clone.appendTo('#someContainer'); // now put the copy somewhere else
```

**EDIT:** Keep in mind when cloning that you don't want to have multiple elements with the same id. It looks like you just put `id="id"` in there for the sake of example, but its still worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id > p').text(function(i,oldValue){
    return "Hello " + oldValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $hello = $(("#id > p")).clone();
$hello.text("Hello");
$hello.prependTo($("#id"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VmAPr/

Of course, you can use *:first* or *:first-child* selectors if necessary and assign intermediate results into the variable or to everything in one line )